JavaScript works on my local server but it does not work on WordPress
I have a template/theme that works perfectly in my local server, but when I move it to WordPress I am getting a "jQuery incompatibility" base on what I have researched.  I have attached images of the code. Everything is working perfect in my end but not in WordPress.



The theme was created using Foundation 6 which uses old jQuery and Webpack. I don't know what is happening because it works perfectly locally. What can I try next?

Please add the code to the question as text, so that we can test and edit it. Images of code are not helpful - and are more work for you to create

The error is saying that nav is undefined, which means that the nav.fl-nav-main element was not in the DOM when the JS ran.

@RoryMcCrossan thank you for taking the time, I apologies, I will

@RoryMcCrossan that is why. It looks like the doom is not loading ? I will double check but the code is working locally. I will check and I will upload the code. Thank you once again!

It is an issue about the query selector that you chose in the js
First you are getting the nav from the doucument, which is ok.
but then you are finding the ul tag from the nav and still using the selector of nav.
The correct code would be these two solutions:
const nav = document.querySelector('nav.fl-nav-main');
const list = nav.querySelector('ul'); //since you are finding the ul from inside the nav, it would work correctly

Or try getting both of them from the document
const nav = document.querySelector('nav.fl-nav-main');
const list = document.querySelector('nav.fl-nav-main ul');

As an extra note, you should wait for the DOM to be loaded, it is a better practice. therefore you can add your code in to a load event like:
 window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('window load OK')
})
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      console.log('DOMContentLoaded OKOK')
    })


Thank you so much! it works now, it was the selector. I was thinking about the load event as well. Once again thank you so much for the help !
